# Windows 10 became slower (+ weird display) after WSL2-Ubuntu install

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v, wsl2

**Edit :**
Okay I retried to install WSL and I finally got it. Enabling wsl/hyper-v has changed the display settings, I don't know why. It changed the resolution, and it added non-physical screens (there should be only 2) :

[image: Screens]

---

After using Cygwin for a long time, I decided to try WSL 2 to use some Unix apps on Windows.

I installed WSL from Powershell 7.3.3 with the `wsl --install` command. The installation was successful and after a reboot, Ubuntu was working fine.

But an annoying problem occurred : After this reboot, Windows 10 became slower. Especially, the navigation in file explorer started to be less smooth. I also noticed that the appearance changed a bit and some visual glitches appeared.

Here is a before/after screen of the file explorer where we can see some differences (the font look different, smaller and blurred, the icons have changed...)

[image: scrot]

I tried to disable Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows features, but it didn't changed anything. I made a backup before this installation so I was able to restore Windows at a previous state.

I really don't understand what happened. Could this be a problem with Hyper-V? I also have *VMware Workstation 17* installed on my machine, but I suppose it has nothing to do with it.

I would like to add that I use Windows 10 Professional with all the updates done.

Comment: Do you have displays with different DPI/scaling factors?

Comment: @DanielB My laptop screen backlight no longer work so I only use a 1920x1080 monitor connected via HDMI, and I adjusted text scale to 125%.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Well if you ask me, both of your screenshots look bad and blurry. ;-) I suggest resetting to 100% and then testing again. Make sure to log out and back in again after changing the scaling. // WSL cannot cause this. Unrelated updates could.

Comment: It's because of the image quality, but before there was no blur at all. x)
@harrymc I already tried, but it didn't find any problem.

Comment: I don't see the connection between WSL and the Explorer display. And I also don't see much difference between the two images, so please replace by better-quality screenshots.

Comment: @harrymc Before (https://imgur.com/5bZt9Wd), after (https://imgur.com/spHhNfF). The differences are : smaller text, visual glitches (that we can see when there is movement), icons change...

Comment: It seems like the resolution of your monitor was changed. Look in *Settings > System > Display* for size of text and for Display resolution.

Comment: @harrymc I retried to install WSL, and you were right, it changed the display settings (resolution, text size, and it added non-physical screens : https://i.imgur.com/L00qBJm.png.) I should have checked that. Thanks !

Comment: I added an answer that if it helped, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poster has found out the the installation of WSL2 has changed the
properties of his monitor. It must be a rare occurrence, since I haven't
seen it mentioned much.

The solution was to check and reset the monitor attributes in
*Settings > System > Display* as regarding resolution and text size.